# How do I set Route attribute in this scenario?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

In MVC WEB API using C# and .Net framework 4.5.1 I have a controller name `MonitoringController` as bellow:

```
public class MonitoringController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("list")]
    public IEnumerable<string> List(string collection)
    {
        return new String[] { "test 1", "test 2" };
    }
}
```

and my routing config is like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.EnsureInitialized();
```

The api works fine on get requests e.g. http://localhost/api/monitoring/list?collection=test

How do I apply Route attribute to make sure it works on http://localhost/api/monitoring/`channels`/list?collection=test

What I thought I should do was :

```
[RoutePrefix("api/monitoring")]
public class MonitoringController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("channels")]
    [ActionName("list")]
    public IEnumerable<string> List(string collection)
    {
        return new String[] { "test 1", "test 2" };
    }
}
```

I cannot get `http://localhost/api/monitoring/channels/list?collection=test` working! What have I done wrong?

I want to be able to have the following routes defined in the controller:

1. /api/monitoring/channels/list
2. /api/monitoring/windows/list
3. /api/monitoring/doors/list

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try flipping the order in which you register the routes:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

And also change `[Route("channels")]` to `[Route("channels/list")]` and dump the `ActionName` attribute.

Better still, don't mix the two approaches and go attribute routing throughout.

If you want the `collection` to be part of the route use a route parameter.

```
[Route("{collection}/list")]
```

See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Your suggestion does not work. I want to be able to have `/api/monitoring/channels/list` and `/api/monitoring/people/list` ...

Comment: So use a route parameter: `[Route("{collection}/list")]`